# Strange feedback in browser for CSP security header

Tags: security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I want to exclude my website `https://www.example.com` from being shown in iframes. The only exception should be itself (having itself in an iframe) and Google (for the Google image search, where the origin page of the image is displayed in an iframe on the left).

So I added this header to my website:

```
CONTENT-SECURITY-POLICY:frame-ancestors 'self' *.example.com *.google.com *.google.de google.com google.de;
```

But this doesn't work the way I planned it. When coming from a google image search URL which shows an image of my page e.g. `http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=[RANDOM STUFF]`

I see this in the console (and no iframe shown):

```
Refused to display 'https://www.example.com/lalala' in a frame
because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"frame-ancestors 'self' *.example.com *.google.com *.google.de google.com google.de".
```

there has to be an error somewhere, but I am not able to find it..

*(tested in the newest Google Chrome & Firefox)*

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could provide an example URL. I can't explain what you're seeing, even if you're on an http page sources without schemes should allow https urls. Did you try specifying https://www.example.com in you policy? You shouldn't have to, that would be a bug but it's all I can think of.

Comment: I tried stating exactly example.com, that did not work. What do you mean with the http / https topic? Is there a chance of failure there?

Comment: Its not really clear what exactly you are asking. Are you trying to load content from a Google image search in an iframe on your page? Are you trying to have your content indexed by Google? Are you trying to load your content on a third page by using an image search as an iframe source? In addition, I believe that @oreoshake was saying that you might need to start the specified urls in your CSP header with either http:// or https://, depending on the protocol used by the intended source.

Comment: @f-stephen-q I tried to specify my question again. I want my site to be displayed in the left side iframe of the picture view in google image search. But as I now just saw EVERY major website doesn't allow that so the standard might not be implemented yet.

Comment: e.g. http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fimages%2Ffb_icon_325x325.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fde-de.facebook.com%2F&h=325&w=325&tbnid=fTKCrFX9aTbCVM%3A&vet=1&docid=Esrrox92ee2e8M&ei=nwhZWL-QEYa6jwPj45qIAQ&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=583&page=0&start=0&ndsp=15&ved=0ahUKEwj_28HeyILRAhUG3WMKHeOxBhEQMwgvKAAwAA&bih=722&biw=1322